# Solving equations involving the sum of all positive divisors of an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define S(n) = the sum of all positive divisors of n. Solve S(n) = n + 6. I have found a trivial solution to this equation to be n = 6. Are there any other possible values of n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $n=25$ is good too, and together with $n=6$ there are no other solutions.

If $n$ is a prime, thus it's only divisible by 1 and itself, $S(n)$ would be $n+1$. If it's not a prime, then it has more than two divisors. If it has only three divisors, then $n=p^2$ and $S(n)$ equals to $n+p+1$, which gives $p=5$ because $S(n)=n+6$. This gives us the number $n=25$. If $n$ has at least four divisors, then $1$ is a divisor, $n$ is a divisor, and we have to have at least two more divisors, but the smaller of the two is at least 2, and the bigger of the two is at least 3, so the sum of divisors is at least $1+n+2+3=n+6$. Since $S(n)=n+6$, these divisors have to be 2 and 3, and we get the only other solution to the problem: $n=6$.

Comment: Great. Thank you.